# Starting VLC through Apache CGI

Tags: apache, bash, cgi, vlc

This is the shell script I am trying to communicate with via CGI

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

QUERY_STRING=4FuSI-LcC54

timeout 600 vlc -vvv http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="$QUERY_STRING" --sout "#transcode{venc=x264{keyint=60,profile=baseline,level=3.0,nocabac},vcodec=x264,vb=150,scale=1,acodec=mp4a,ab=96,channels=2,samplerate=48000}:rtp{dst=10.4.175.251,port=10000,mux=ts}"

echo "VLC Started!"
```

QUERY_STRING is temporarily set to a value for testing purposes. Normally, it should hold HTTP GET params. I can evoke this script just fine without errors when I evoke it normally from bash. However, if I try to evoke it from an HTTP GET Request, VLC crashes and goes through a shutdown phase.

Comment: Does vlc print anything sensible to stdout or stderr?

Comment: Yes, it prints "Shutting Down, Bye Bye!" According to the error logs in apache, it seems that all goes well until the lua interface in VLC randomly requests shutdown.